# Pygame how to find the nearest sprite in an array and lock onto it?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pygame, distance

I have a missile sprite that, if I shoot it. It should go to the nearest enemy sprite. Im not how how to go on about this. I am fully aware that we will be using some distance formulae but this is not the problem. The problem is cycling through the enemies in a list and finding the enemy that is closest to the missile.

I have already tried using for loops but this is as far as I can think for now. I have looked at other posts but none share the same type of problem. Only for singular sprites that are not already in lists.

Missile class

```
class Missile:
    missile = pygame.image.load("Missile-1.png")
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.yvel = 15
        self.xvel = 5
    def draw(self,win):
        win.blit(missile,(self.x,self.y))
    def chase(self):
        for enemy in enemies:
            #some code
```

Arrays:

```
missiles = []
enemies = []
```

I expect the missile to go towards the nearest enemy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) and the function [`.distance_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to) to calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) distance between 2 points.

```py
def chase(self):
    pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.x, self.y)
    enemy = min([e for e in enemies], key=lambda e: pos.distance_to(pygame.math.Vector2(e.x, e.y)))
```

Explanation:

`lambda e: pos.distance_to(pygame.math.Vector2(e.x, e.y))` calcaultes the distance of the argument `e` to the `pygame.math.Vector2` object `pos`.
[`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) finds the minimum element in an [*iterable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). The "minimum" value is given by the function which is set to the `key` argument.

`pos` is initialized by the position of the `Missile`. For each element of `enemies` the distance to `pos` is calculated and the enemy which is closest to `pos` is returned by `min`.

---

Of course this can be further simplified by manually calculating the squared euclidean distance:

```py
def chase(self):
    enemy = min([e for e in enemies], key=lambda e: pow(e.x-self.x, 2) + pow(e.y-self.y, 2))
```